# Extend django.rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer to model property fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using this serializer to query and return some json objects.

```
class MyModelPathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('setup', 'path')
    depth=1
```

I am interesting in returning a property of of my model rather than a field though.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    setup = models.ForeignKey(Setup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def path(self):
         return '/some/path/'
```

Is there a way to modify the serializer class so that also properties are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` to return the property of your model instance. This is a read-only field.

```
class MyModelPathSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    path = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("setup", "path")
        depth = 1

    def get_path(self, model_instance):
        return model_instance.path
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield